# Help with people, people_experimental stacks

Tags: ros, leg-detector, people

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to do leg detection with LIDAR, and the leg_detector node from people_experimental looks perfect for the job.  The only problem is that I cannot find any documentation on how to use it, and so far my attempts have failed.

[Here](http://pr.willowgarage.com/wiki/Leg_detection) is a wiki page introducing the leg_detector node.  This page has a broken link, http://home.willowgarage.com/wgwiki/Leg_Detection which supposedly has documentation.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could share their experiences with the stack, or point me to the the right documentation :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29605/help-with-people,-people_experimental-stacks/) by [bkx](https://answers.ros.org/users/1731/bkx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 145 on 2012-03-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-03-12**:
I am currently working on a forked version that may be able to help. I'll post a full version later in the week.

**Comment by [bkx](https://answers.ros.org/users/1731/bkx/) on 2012-03-13**:
That would be great, please post a link here once you release it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[An unstable/undocumented version of the people_experimental stack is available here.](http://code.google.com/p/wu-robotics/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fpeople2) It has the benefit of doing leg detection without needing facial input in order to recognize people.

I am currently in the process of getting this integrated into Willow's people stack with the help of Caroline Pantofaru. Any suggestions are welcome.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0